# iOS 6: How do I segue from inside a tableview embedded in a nav controller TO another VC?

Tags: ios, segue, viewcontroller

I have an initial 'parent menu' view controller with a 'photos' button (more buttons to come like 'events').

From the Photos button I have a simple ctrl-drag segue to a navigation controller which has a tableview as it's first view(albums), collections view(thumbs), then imageview(fullsize).

The problem I am having is:
I want to be able to segue back to the initial simple 'parent menu' view controller from the first table view after the nav controller.

I tried:

- dragging a button into the table view's top menu bar area (it was considered a UINavigationItem) and dragging a segue back to the menu... didn't work.
- setup outlet from button in the tableview menu area to its parent view and calling [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"BackToMenu" sender: self]; from there, didn't work.
- dragging a button into the table view as a last item and ctrl+dragging it as a segue to the menu: didn't work.
- tried a segue going back from the nav controller to the menu and manually calling it, but the outlet function connected to the 'menu' button I dragged into the tableview top back NEVER gets hit.

What am I missing?

I plan to have a few navigation controllers going out from the menu page in the storyboard from multiple buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wound up doing was making the nav controller first before anything and then my menu page was first with buttons down each respective path.

on the above: The ctrl+drag didnt work from the nav bar button, kept totally blowing up.

I did not realize I could go from nav controller to a regular view controller first. thought it needed to go to table view first since when you drag out a nav it comes paired with a table.

If I had 10+ 'points' in this strange forum I'd post a screen shot of the storyboard.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You can drag a "Bar Button Item" to the left side of the first table view after the navigation controller.  From there, do the control-drag back from the bar button item to the initial view controller, and choose a "modal" segue.  While this answers your question, as @jrturton said in the comments below, this isn't optimized, because it will create a new instance.

If you want to do this programmatically (which will return to the existing instance), create an IBAction for the Bar Button Item on the table view controller.  For example in iOS 6:

```
-(IBAction)returnToParentMenu:(id)sender {
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

or in iOS 5:

```
-(IBAction)returnToParentMenu:(id)sender {
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: This will create a new instance of the original patent view controller.

Comment: Your edited answer is correct (the code part). Control-dragging a segue "back" to the parent is wrong, for the reasons in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a segue for this. You can create a button in your table view and link it to an action in your table view which dismisses the currently presented view controller (I'm assuming your segue that presented the navigation controller stack in the first place was of a "modal" type):

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Alternatively, you can look into "Unwind Segues" but I haven't used these myself yet so wouldn't like to include details here.

Comment: His initial controller which he is trying to return to is not part of the navigation stack.

Comment: ... and to be clear, calling popViewControllerAnimated: from the Navigation Controller's Root View Controller will have no effect.

Comment: @JShapiro you're right, I misread that part of the question, and it should be dismissing a modal or presented view controller instead. Doesn't make your answer right though ;)